# count adjacent elements in vector with repetitions - matlab

Tags: matlab, vector, counting

```
v = [1,1,1,2,3,3,4,4,4,4,2,3,3,3,1,1]
```

I'm looking for a way to count adjacent elements in vector `c` without loosing the repetitions.
This is the desired output:

```
c = 
      3  1  2  4  1  3  2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Answer](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/330902-counting-consecutive-values-in-a-matrix) from **Mathworks**

```
% code
v = [1,1,1,2,3,3,4,4,4,4,2,3,3,3,1,1];
c  = diff([0 find(diff(v)) numel(v)])

% output
c = [3  1  2  4  1  3  2]
```

Answer (score 2):

Use diff() to spot the change points, then get the indexes of those points.

```matlab
id = diff(v)==0; 
idx = strfind([id 0], 0);
c = [idx(1) diff(idx)]
```

Output:

```
c =

     3     1     2     4     1     3     2
```